# LARAVEL: How to use Open Close Principle of SOLID principles?

Tags: php, laravel, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I have a following structure to use **Open Close Principle**

```
class Payment{ 

    //this is not a model class
    // according to OC principle this class should not focus on the implementation

    private $paymentInterface;

    public function __construct(PaymentInterface $paymentInterface)
    {
        $this->paymentInterface = $paymentInterface;
    }


    //so store method does not know which implementation it will get
    public function store($request,$id)
    {
        return $this->paymentInterface->store($request,$id);
    }

}
```

**Interface**

```
interface PaymentInterface{
    public function store($request,$id = null);
}
```

**Payment Service Class containing implementation**

```
class PaymentService implements PaymentInterface{
    public function store($request,$id = null){
        //payment store logic is here
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class PaymentsController extends Controller{

    protected $payment;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->payment = new Payment(new PaymentService);
    }

    public function storePayment(PaymentRequest $request, $id)
    {
        try {
             $response = $this->payment->store($request,$id);
             return redirect()->route($this->route.'.index')->with($response['status'],$response['message']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->vendorDashboard($e);
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is:**
Is it correct approach to use **Open-Close-Principle** ?
Using above code I can tell controller that I can use PaymentService class for the implementation.

```
$payment = new Payment(new PaymentService);
return $payment->store($request,$id);
```

If later I want to make a payment in different way e.g. make a payment through invoice then I can create new controller, write new implementation in new class e.g. **InvoicePaymentService** and tell Payment class to use InvoicePaymentService as implementation

```
$payment = new Payment(new InvoicePaymentService);
return $payment->store($request,$id);
```

OR

```
$payment = new Payment(new PayPalPaymentService);
return $payment->store($request,$id);
```

OR

```
$payment = new Payment(new AliPayPaymentService);
return $payment->store($request,$id);
```

I know I can bind Interface with a class through a service provider but if I want to implement a different payment implementation then I will not be able to change the class, right ?

If I am doing it in wrong way please let me know.

Comment: "but if I want to implement a different payment implementation" - do you mean different Payment class implementation?

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned in question. Like I want to do payment with PayPal or AliPay

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what service container stands for. You should use [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#contextual-binding)

Assuming you have an interface: **FooInterface**

And you have two concrete implementations: **GoodFoo** and **BadFoo**

In order to inject different implementations to controllers (or other classes) **you must tell it to laravel.**

```
$this->app->when(GoodController::class)
      ->needs(FooInterface::class)
      ->give(function () {
            return new GoodFoo();
      });


$this->app->when(BadController::class)
      ->needs(FooInterface::class)
      ->give(function () {
            return new BadFoo();
      });
```

And controllers should be:

```
class GoodController extends Controller
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

class BadController extends Controller
{
    protected $foo;

    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}
```

Please note that most of the time laravel promotes bad software design principles and it rather hard to practise SOLID principles in laravel.

Comment: Great. this is what I was finding on the internet

Comment: That means we don't have to write a generic class. We can directly connect implementations with interfaces on the basis of different controllers, right ?

Comment: It depends. If you have just one implementation and you don't plan to add another one in the future it's okay to not use an interface.